# bq load command for timestamp field

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am running into an error when I try to load values to a table with bq load command for a timestamp field, but the same value seems to work fine when I do direct insert on the GUI.

1. Table LOG is already created with created_time  field type as TIMESTAMP.
2. This seems to insert just fine.
   `Insert into testdataset.LOG (id, created_time) values (123,"2014-09-27T12:30:00.45Z");`
3. This fails with error  `bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 --autodetect  --noreplace myproject:testdataset.LOG ./test.csv`

Conents of CSV :

```
"ID","CREATED_TIME"
1,"2014-09-27T12:30:00.45Z"
2,"2014-09-27T12:30:00.45Z"
```

Error as below :

```
Field CREATED_TIME has changed type from TIMESTAMP to STRING
```

If I add schema to the command as below :

`bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 --autodetect  --noreplace myproject:testdataset.LOG ./test.csv ID:INTEGER,CREATED_TIME:TIMESTAMP`

I get error  : `Field CREATED_TIME has changed mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE`

Update :

**Issue with me was the order of the fields and the quotes in csv...I also had to change the field created_time from REQUIRED to NULLABLE.. once I did these it worked  My new CSV looks like below :

```
    CREATE_TIME,ID
2014-09-27T12:30:00.45Z,123
2014-09-27T12:30:00.45Z,123
```

**

Comment: I have tried to reproduce your issue but following your instructions worked for me just fine. What version of the SDK are you using?

I am using Google Cloud SDK 271.0.0, bq 2.0.50

Comment: Issue with me was the order of the fields and the quotes in csv...I also had to change the field created_time from REQUIRED to NULLABLE.. once I did these it worked  My new CSV looks like below :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your CSV is a bit malformed. Try removing the quotes altogether:

```
ID,CREATED_TIME
1,2014-09-27T12:30:00.45Z
2,2014-09-27T12:30:00.45Z
```

Answer (score 1):

If your schema exists, you don't need to ask for schema auto-detection. Let BigQuery casting your field in the target field format, if it can. For this, simply remove the `--autodetect` option

```
bq load --source_format=CSV --skip_leading_rows=1 --noreplace myproject:testdataset.LOG ./test.csv
```

Comment: thanks! its a good point. I had tried that already but it didn work.

Comment: I reuse your CSV and your column definition type and it worked on my side!! What's your error?

Comment: Issue with me was the order of the fields and the quotes in csv...I also had to change the field created_time from required to nullable.. once i did these it worked